# Excel VBA program comparing Cell values says they do not match, but they do

Tags: excel, vba

This is such a basic program, but I'm obviously doing something wrong. I have a spreadsheet with numeric values in all Cells, then I am comparing three totals, the first is a SUM of the 10 cells above it, the next is retrieved from SSMS and the third is captured from screenshots by Snagit. These should, and mostly are, all be the same …
The program Hides all the Columns then scrolls through them and UnHides them if there is a MisMatch in the Total Fields. Except it doesn't, it says there is a problem in almost every Column !!! If someone can please explain and / or help then you may just save my sanity !!!

```vb
Sub FindMisMatches()

    Columns("B:EE").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    
    Dim SUMvalue As Variant
    Dim SQLvalue As Variant
    Dim COBOLvalue As Variant
    Dim MisMatch As String
    
    For i = 2 To 135
        MisMatch = "No"
        Cells(15, i).Value = ""
        SUMvalue = Cells(12, i).Value
        SQLvalue = Cells(13, i).Value
        COBOLvalue = Cells(14, i).Value
        If SUMvalue = SQLvalue Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            MisMatch = "Yes"
        End If
        If SUMvalue = COBOLvalue Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            MisMatch = "Yes"
        End If
        If SQLvalue = COBOLvalue Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            MisMatch = "Yes"
        End If
        If MisMatch = "Yes" Then
            Cells(15, i).Value = "XXXXX"
            Cells(12, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Cells(13, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Cells(14, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Cells(15, i).Select
            ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image: The Spreadsheet]

Comment: Formatting is something to consider as well, if you don't care about the exact same datatype, you can convert them to strings and go from there IE: `If Cstr(SUMvalue) = Cstr(SQLvalue) Then`, even so, you probably may have differences in the nth decimal which is not visible, so proceed with caution depending on your ultimate goal

Comment: Testing decimal values for equality is sometimes tricky  - what you see in the cell is not necessarily the exact value.

Comment: Or you could define a delta that is acceptable and then compare to that by subtracting the values, e.g. delta = 0.0005, SUMValue = 1.0008 - SQLValue = 1 then diff is not ok - but whith sumvalue = 1.0003 it would be ok

Comment: I know there is a restriction in Excel where anything over 15 digits just gets the following digits replaced by zeroes, and this spreadsheet does include some 18 digit numbers, but these early digits are, well, should be, exactly as displayed ! For instance, using Debug, all 3 of my values for Column B show as being 61.2, and the Cells are formatted as Number with 1 Decimal Place.

Comment: Can you `debug.print` the mismatched values and paste the output for a few of the columns?  15 digits is the max precision for Excel - you can't accurately store anything with 18 digits in Excel.

Comment: It all looks exactly as I'd expect ...

 6.7 
 6.7 
 6.6 
 61.2 
 61.2 
 61.2 
 565.8 
 565.8 
 565.8 
 41714 
 41714 
 41714

Comment: No other ideas - maybe try to narrow down where the mismatch occurs in each case (which pair(s) of numbers) and see if there's any pattern?

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Have you looked at the types you are getting back? I asume you have rounding issues and type mismatches but hard to judge by only looking at it..

Comment: try do math with values, like x-y...
maybe data type is misbehaving..